# Get commit files list in excel

Tags: java, excel, git

I need a list of all the files which were committed in the last couple of days in an excel with the user name who committed the file, date, list of files committed.

I have tried this command.

```
git log --after "11-06-2019" --before "28-06-2019" --pretty="%cn committed %h on %cd for %s" --name-only > master.xls
```

excepted output is formatted excel, here I am getting a list of the files, user name, date in one single column.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what the problem is?

Comment: I am getting a list of the files, user name, date in one single column. i want username in one column, date in second and list of files in third

Comment: Git will likely output text. I don't think you can use any extension you like and expect it to work flawlessly.

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes but is there any way i can get it?

Comment: I know you can fill out excel spreadsheets in Java, but I'm unsure if you can get git commits without performing terminal-based actions, such as piping the output of `git log` into a file.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267540/text-to-xls-file-creation

Answer (score 2):

The closest I could get was:

```
user,Wed Jun 26 11:16:41 2019 +0200,

lib/script.py
user,Tue Jun 25 15:32:21 2019 +0200,

lib/script.py
```

I get it with:

```
git log --after "11-06-2019" --before "28-06-2019" --pretty="%cn,%cd,%b" --name-only > master.csv
```

Instead someone knows a better way, you'll have an extra-step to replace `\n\n` by a `,`.

Also, use CSV instead of `.xls`: xls are binary files, you're not supposed to write text directly in it.